# UICollectionView: remove margin between cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've a simply collection view and I would like to display a grid (2columns x N rows) with vertical scrolling.

So I implement **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** methods:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let collectionViewWidth: CGFloat  = collectionView.frame.size.width 
    let cellSize: CGFloat = collectionViewWidth / 2.0
    return CGSizeMake(cellSize, cellSize);
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
   return 0.0
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0
}
```

Despite this, cells in collection view are still separated by white space.. where I'm wrong?

Comment: This cannot be your real code (`cellFeedWidth` is not defined).

Comment: is `cell` and `cellFeedWidth` in line 3 and 4 a typo?

Comment: ops, I correct, sorry

Comment: of course, code in my project is the same but with different names

Answer (score 3):

Per the method names, you are giving the **minimum** values, not the absolute or maximum ones.

If you want your cells to be layouted without spaces, you must give them a width equal to the width of your screen divided by the number of cells per row you want to display.

For example, on a 320 pixels wide screen, you will fit four 80x80 cells without empty spaces.  If you give them a width of 60 pixels instead, you will end with 20 pixels of empty space that will be given equally between each cells.

Comment: yo!! so problem was my width calculation. I substitute with UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 2, and now works

Comment: And yet the code above works perfectly in my test project. Are you sure your collectionViews layout constraints are OK. Its a code stink that you need to input the main screens width to get this to work.